# LSTM forecasting tensorflow use of batch, repeat and shuffle

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, forecasting

I came across these two pages - [page 1](https://www.kaggle.com/code/ndzhda/beer-production-forecast-1996/notebook) and [page 2](https://analyticsindiamag.com/how-to-do-multivariate-time-series-forecasting-using-lstm/) which use LSTM for forecasting.

the second link uses below code:

```
batch_size = 256
buffer_size = 150

train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
train_data = train_data.cache().shuffle(buffer_size).batch(batch_size).repeat()

val_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_vali, y_vali))
val_data = val_data.batch(batch_size).repeat()
```

while the first link doesn't use similar code at all. I have relatively small dataset.

Please guide me regarding when I should use above code and when I shouldn't. I saw stackoverflow posts regarding `batch`, `repeat`, `shuffle` but I am not clear. Please keep in mind I am building a forecasting model

Comment: .shuffle(buffer_size) basically just randomly arranges your input data. buffer_size reflects a parameter to determine the randomness. It makes it randomn, but ensures reproduceability, because the randomnes is always the same for the same buffer_size (of course also depends on the machine setting, so it won't be the same all the time). .repeat() repeats the input and gives output with the same shape (if no axis is specified, then the output is flattened). batch determines the "pieces" of data which are later put piece by piece into the model fitting.

Comment: if my data has 200 observations then does repeat passes that same data multiple time during one epochs?

Comment: for example, will it send 200*repeat datapoints?

Comment: I think in the context how it is used here it is to tell tensorflow to keep looping over your dataset (otherwise, once it ran out of data/end of an epoch, TensorFlow would give an  error).